# How can I loop through variables by their names?

Tags: c++, c

Suppose I have **N** float variables `x0`, `x1`, `x2`, ..., `xn`.

I basically want to loop through each of them and sum them all in a final variable `sum`.

I'm in a context where I cannot make use of data structures like arrays, vectors, etc. If it helps, in my context **N** is always less than 10.

Is it possible to make a `for` loop to do this?

---

My first thought was using macros like the concatenate (`##`) or something like that but I guess it won't fit my case.

Comment: I'm writing a shader, I don't have access to data structures. It's just like C but without data structures.

Comment: Why can't you use arrays or vectors?

Comment: You can't have loops in macros.

Comment: I'm not familiar with shaders.

Comment: I was thinking about a concat macro, then in my for loop, I would use something like (`x ## i`), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Concatenation happens at compile time, it can't refer to run-time variables.

Comment: I just looked up shaders, it says they usually run on the GPU. These often have vector-processing instructions, you should be able to use that.

Comment: https://hub.packtpub.com/working-with-shaders-in-c-to-create-3d-games/

Comment: How about this? Declare a `float*` pointer and allocate some needed bytes. Then you index them by increasing the pointer by one.

Comment: Is the shader code actually C or C++, as the tags on the question suggest? Shader code are usually written in languages like GLSL, which are different from typical C or C++.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki you are right, it's not the same, but is very similar. I'm using HLSL. Anyway my question is regarding C/C++.

Comment: @Daniel -- Write a code generator that generates the code you are looking for.  Run the code generator (and you *can* use anything, vectors, arrays, etc. when you developed the code generator). Then it will generate the code and you just stick it into your application.

Comment: `x0, x1, ..., xn` are `n+1` variables, not `n`

Comment: *"I'm in a context where I cannot make use of data structures like arrays"* - ¿and what kind of context could it be? Pack of variables named like x0, x1... is certainly a code smell.

Comment: @Daniel The comments actually add relevant info to the question. As the question reads, a reasonable assumption to make would be to assume you're dealing with a mean teacher. If your first comment was part of the question, a completely different answer would have been possible: [Some shaders actually allow for arrays](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Arrays)

Comment: you may have to declare variables in a function and manipulate its stack frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure whether it fits your needs, but you can try something like:

```
#define SUM_X0 (x0)
#define SUM_X1 (SUM_X0 + x1)
#define SUM_X2 (SUM_X1 + x2)
#define SUM_X3 (SUM_X2 + x3)
#define SUM_X4 (SUM_X3 + x4)
#define SUM_X5 (SUM_X4 + x5)
#define SUM_X6 (SUM_X5 + x6)
#define SUM_X7 (SUM_X6 + x7)
#define SUM_X8 (SUM_X7 + x8)
#define SUM_X9 (SUM_X8 + x9)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5;
    if (scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &x0, &x1, &x2, &x3, &x4, &x5) != 6) {
        printf("error");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%d\n", SUM_X0);
    printf("%d\n", SUM_X1);
    printf("%d\n", SUM_X2);
    printf("%d\n", SUM_X3);
    printf("%d\n", SUM_X4);
    printf("%d\n", SUM_X5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this a `for` loop and getting the variable by the for's index? I'm guessing it's impossible, since the macros run at compile time...

Comment: @Daniel you cannot loop over independent variables, you have to use some kind of array (either c style of c++ ones)

Comment: The old version of the answer fits my question better! Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel old version does not work properly

Comment: This promotes the worst kind of copypasta and it does not actually do anything remotely similar to *"loop through variables by their names"* asked.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

Just allocate the memory using something other than arrays. Arrays or array-like data structures would be the most natural thing to use here, but since whoever created this task wanted to make your life harder by putting those restrictions in place, you could simply use functions that just provide you with memory that you could use for storing the elements.

In C you'd use `malloc`, but in C++ using an allocator for this is preferrable.

```
/**
 * Execute the desired logic with \p inputText as content of the input
 */
void Test(char const* inputText)
{
    std::allocator<float> allocator;

    size_t const n = 9;

    auto deleter = [n, &allocator](float* mem) {allocator.deallocate(mem, n); };

    // notAnArray makes sure the memory gets freed by calling allocator.deallocate(<allocated memory>, n)
    std::unique_ptr<float[], decltype(deleter)> notAnArray{ allocator.allocate(n), deleter };

    std::istringstream input{inputText};

    size_t count = 0;

    for (; count != n; ++count)
    {
        if (!(input >> notAnArray[count]))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << count << "  elements read\n";

    float sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != count; ++i)
    {
        sum += notAnArray[i];
    }

    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << "\n------------------------\n";
}

int main()
{
    Test("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10");
    Test("");
    Test("5 4 32 1");
}
```

#### Option 2

This approach is more hacky and relies on the fact that you may not use data structures, but custom types are not excluded from use.

You could simply create a struct holding the variables which ensures they are stored one after the other in memory enabling you to use a pointer to the first member variable as if it was the first element of an array:

```
constexpr size_t MaxCount = 9;

struct NotAnArray
{
    float x0;
    float x1;
    float x2;
    float x3;
    float x4;
    float x5;
    float x6;
    float x7;
    float x8;
};

static_assert((offsetof(NotAnArray, x8) - offsetof(NotAnArray, x0)) == (sizeof(float) * (MaxCount - 1)));

/**
 * Execute the desired logic with \p inputText as content of the input
 */
void Test(char const* inputText)
{
    NotAnArray storage;
    float* const notAnArray = &storage.x0;

    std::istringstream input{inputText};

    size_t count = 0;

    for (; count != MaxCount; ++count)
    {
        if (!(input >> notAnArray[count]))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << count << "  elements read\n";

    float sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != count; ++i)
    {
        sum += notAnArray[i];
    }

    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << "\n------------------------\n";
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter An explanation for the download would be preferred. Without one there's no possibility to improve; there isn't a possibility for other readers to know what's wrong...